# Wierd expression in Maple ; $min(0, signum(x^2+y^2)*\infty)$

Tags: maple

Im getting this as return in Maple;

$min(0, signum(x^2+y^2)*\infty)$

What is it suppose to mean?

Its in the answer of the follwoing;

minimize(P(x, y, z, w);

```
2 min(0, signum(x^2+y^2)infinity + min(-6 x, 6 x)

+ min(-6 y, 6 y) + min(-6 z, 6 z) + min(-6 w, 6 w) + C y w

+ C x z - D x z - D y z
```

P is a polynomial in 4 variables x,y,z,w and with some constraints on the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weakness.  My guess is that the answer will come out fine if you first do

```
assume(x::real,y::real, z::real, w::real);
```

What it means is that you need to either add a factor of `0` to the answer when `signum(x^2+y^2)` is 1 (which it essentially always is); if `x^2+y^2` could even be $< 0$, then this would evaluate to $-\infty$.

Comment: now it addad some "~", you know what that means?

Comment: Maple adds some ~ to the end of names of variables that have assumptions on them.  That's standard.